How to select Sales Tab in Transaction BP from ABAP
I want to start the transaction BP with the "Sales"(Vertrieb) View, but my code below just opens the default starting Page:

Do I need a subheader-ID? If yes, how do I find it? If no, what else? I'm getting crazy on this, because I don't find much for this, not even in our Systems.
That's my code so far:
METHOD open_bupa.
  DATA(request) = NEW cl_bupa_navigation_request( ).
  request->set_partner_number( i_bupa ).
  request->set_bupa_activity( request->gc_activity_display ).
  request->set_maintenance_id( request->gc_maintenance_id_partner ).
  request->set_bupa_partner_role( VALUE #( role = 'ZDEB' bpview = 'ZDEB' ) ).

  DATA(options) = NEW cl_bupa_dialog_joel_options( ).
  options->set_locator_visible( abap_false ).
  SET PARAMETER ID: 'VKO' FIELD i_current_row-sales_org,
                    'VTW' FIELD i_current_row-distribution_channel,
                    'SPA' FIELD i_current_row-sector.
  cl_bupa_dialog_joel=>start_with_navigation(
      EXPORTING
        iv_request              = request
        iv_options              = options
        iv_in_new_internal_mode = abap_false
        iv_in_new_window        = abap_false
      EXCEPTIONS
        already_started         = 1
        not_allowed             = 2
        OTHERS                  = 3
    ).
  IF sy-subrc = 2.
    MESSAGE i011.
  ENDIF.
ENDMETHOD.


Found it.
SPRO -> IMG -> Cross-Application Components -> SAP Business Partner -> Business Partner -> Basic Settings -> Business Partner Roles -> Define BP Roles
For the Roles.
Transaction BUSD for the ID: Mark the corresponding role and click on Sub-Header-ID on the left

You need Sub header Tab, and have to make additional method call request->set_bupa_sub_header_tab( 'XXXXXX' ).
The 6 character sub header tab name can be found from TBZ3A table.
With the below additional call, it always defaults to "Status" tab
request->set_bupa_sub_header_tab( 'BUP040' ).


Yea, but i dont want to select a tab, but the Sales View (In top in the Menu Bar)

aah ok. The question heading said sales tab, that's why I got confused. Glad that you were able to find the answer.

Yeah maybe a bit misleading, but i meant the Tab, like the View of it. English isnt my mother tongue
